# Conditions in PreFlow policies

Tags: apigee

Can I have conditions mentioned in the PreFlow section of the policy?

something like e.g.

```
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <Name>Some Common step</Name>
            </Step>
            <Condition>request.verb = "GET"</Condition>
        </Request>
        <Response/>
    </PreFlow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Apigee docs](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/flow-variables-and-conditions#variables) even provide this example of a POST conditional within a preflow:

```
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
  <Request>
    <Step>
        <Condition>request.verb equals "POST"</Condition>
        <Name>VerifyApiKey</Name>
    </Step>
  </Request>
```

Comment: I was basically looking for conditions at the PreFlow level. The conditions within the <Step> level works fine though. This makes me place conditions within every step. However thanks for your reply.